# How do I reference the Sqlite db file in the App_Data folder for my ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, data-access-layer, appdata

I'm currently storing my sqlite db file in the App_Data folder as per ASP.NET best pattern and practices.

Currently I'm using the following in the webconfig:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="sqlite"  
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MyDB; Version=3;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and the following in code:

```
       public SqliteDAO(string path)
        {
            Connection = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path );
        }

//...

//where path = |DataDirectory|MyDB
```

It causes sqlite to make a NEW database (with no tables in it), and thus none of my data access calls work, since they aren't finding the table names. How do I reference the sqlite db file in the App_Data folder from my WebApplication code??

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Server.MapPath to your db file.  So it would be something like

```
Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\Your.db");
```

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but how would you do this from a file that isn't a "CodeBehind" file, where you don't have the Server object? Do you have to pass the server object, or the path from a Code-Behind file?

Comment: @kdmurray - you can use this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

Comment: Thanks Ben. I managed to find a solution to this myself too, by passing the HttpContext object to the other class:

MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.myFunc(this.Context);

Comment: @kdmurray, it is bit late but you can always use static `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` object if you are working in asp.net and don't need to pass it around.